# INFORMIX: How can I store query result into a variable and echo it to the system as a string?

Tags: informix

Is it possible to do something like this inside an Informix stored procedure :

```
DEFINE my_data VARCHAR(255);
LET meta = (select count(*), something  from tab11);
SYSTEM 'echo '|| meta;
```

Comment: What's your question? Take a look at [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You capture the output using an `INTO` clause and wrap the `SELECT` in a [`FOREACH`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1331.htm).  This fetches one row of data at a time, and you need separate variables for each column that you select.  You can then manipulate those into a bigger string.

You can then use [`SYSTEM`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1358.htm).

However, the output of `echo` will be sent to `/dev/null` (or `NUL:`).  If that's what you want, fine — but why?  If not, you'll need to organize redirection to somewhere else for yourself.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE echo(str VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT 'hello world');
    DEFINE cmd VARCHAR(255);
    LET cmd = "echo " || str || " >>/Users/jleffler/tmp/arcana.out";
    SYSTEM cmd;
END PROCEDURE;
EXECUTE PROCEDURE echo();
EXECUTE PROCEDURE echo("The world is your oyster");
DROP PROCEDURE echo;
```

You'll need to adjust the file name to suit your purposes — the chances are high that you don't have my home directory on your machine.

Example output file:

```
hello world
The world is your oyster
```

Permissions on file and directories leading to file:

```
         2 drwxr-xr-x     root    wheel 2017-05-24 17:17:16 /
    169236 drwxr-xr-x     root    admin 2016-09-20 12:46:37 /Users
    609973 drwxr-xr-x jleffler    staff 2017-05-24 17:18:45 /Users/jleffler
   1670154 drwxr-xr-x jleffler    staff 2017-05-24 17:19:02 /Users/jleffler/tmp
  63140467 -rw-r--r-- jleffler    staff 2017-05-24 17:19:02 /Users/jleffler/tmp/arcana.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with everything @Jonathan Leffler mentioned above. Here is another example where the select the statement returns a single integer value similar to what you have have shown in your question.

```
create procedure test(); 
DEFINE my_data int;
LET my_data = (select count(*) from systables);
system 'echo ' || my_data || ' > /tmp/my_data';
end procedure;
execute procedure test();
```

In my test system, the output of the select statement

```
select count(*) from systables;

  (count(*)) 
         113

1 row(s) retrieved.
```

When I execute the procedure, the result of the system statement is the file /tmp/my_data.

```
cat /tmp/my_data
113
```

In short, it is certainly possible to achieve what you are looking to do. However depending on the result set of the select statement, you may need more complex handling inside the stored procedure.